# PHP preg_match_all giving offset of -1 in addition to correct matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This appears to be strange behavior, or perhaps I don't understand regular expressions so well...

I'm using this to find all the xref and trailer objects in a PDF file:

```
preg_match_all('@(\nxref\r?\n)|(\strailer\s)@',$pdfcontent,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

print_r gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
xref
                    [1] => 13235519
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
trailer
                    [1] => 13299371
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
xref
                    [1] => 13235519
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                    [1] => -1
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
trailer
                    [1] => 13299371
                )
        )
)
```

Why is there a position of -1 for xref?

Comment: -1 for regex matching typically means no match found.

Comment: There was a match found. It gave both the match and a -1 value for a second occurance.

Comment: Could someone explain this to me, or are you just going to laugh at my stupidity while I scratch my head?

Comment: While I am not one of the downvoters, it is not a very clear question. Your question is "PHP preg_match_all giving offset of -1" and my comment answers for you.  You don't really say what you are trying to find with your regex pattern, so how could we posibly know if it is right or wrong.  So please add what you are searching for.

Comment: The PDF file is 10MB, not something I can post here. All my code does is exactly as I posted, which is search for occurances of "xref" or "trailer" in the file. That is not the question. The question is whether this is normal behavior for preg_match_all. If you look at the print_r you can see that index 0 has 1 find for each, index 1 has 2 finds including a -1, and index 2 has 2 finds except one is an empty array. I don't think this sounds like regular behavior. Perhaps the downvoters would like to explain if it is so obvious to them.

Comment: To answer your title, the `-1` offset is returned *alternatively*, not in *addition*. You have an alternative `(a)|(b)` match group in your pattern. So it can very well return offsets and matches for the `xref`, but a non-match for the `trailer`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems inconsistent. I resorted to checking both `isset` and `>=0` to ensure the ghost matches aren't included when looping through the offsets. Strange thing is that this script was working fine yesterday, without me changing anything, and on the same file, then it started giving errors only today which I traced down to the ghost matches popping up. Perhaps a PHP update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is the normal behaviour, mostly undocumented though. The `-1` offset is **also** used for absent matches.

To answer your title, the `-1` offset is returned *alternatively*, not in *addition*. You have an alternative `(a)|(b)` match group in your pattern. So it can very well return offsets and matches for the `xref`, but a non-match for the `trailer`.

This is not mentioned explicitely in the PHP manual page. But PCRE [documents it cursorily](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) with:

> [...] When  this happens, both values in the offset pairs corre-
>          sponding to unused subpatterns are set to -1.

You can reproduce it with a simpler example:

```
preg_match_all('/(a)|(b)|(c)/', "abc", $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
and print_r($m);
```

[Have a look]. The behaviour is a bit confusing. It seems the `-1` is used as offset for the early non-matches. But subsequent failed matches are just absent in the result array. This example gives `[0,-1,-1]` and `[undef,1,-1]` and `[undef,undef,2]` for example. I would conclude it's some hazy behaviour in the [PHP wrapper](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#L524).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you have 2 `xref` without a `trailer` in between. Something like:

```
xref
shgfjqhfkj

xref
 shgfjqhfkj
 trailer
```

And the matching groups are wrong.

I'd change the regex with:

```
'@(\nxref\r?\n|\strailer\s)@'
```